# FileNotFoundException when reading file - No such file or directory

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone to help me catch what is wrong with my code?

Path:
`src/dictionary.txt`

Code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\dictionary.txt"));`
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\dictionary (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at p26.WordReconstruction.generateDictionary(WordReconstruction.java:13)
    at p26.WordReconstruction.main(WordReconstruction.java:24)
```

Comment: I got a syntax error when I tried that `Invalid escape sequence`

Comment: I'm using the same thing and it seems to work. Are you sure there's no other place where there might be some error? What's line 120?

Comment: @AustinTruong no, you didn't. `"/src/dictionary.txt"` != ``"\src\dictionary.txt"``

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine, are you sure that your java class file is in a directory which contains src directory which contains dictionary.txt?

Comment: Have you tried to use an absolute pass?

Comment: Ah I tried `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/dictionary.txt (No such file or directory)` Still getting the error. Yeah I am pretty sure it is in the src folder.

Comment: try ".\\src\\dictionary.txt", be sure that it's dictionary.txt, not dictionary.TXT nor dictionary.tXt

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Answer (score 5):

`/src/dictionary.txt` is not the same as `src/dictionary.txt`. The first is in the `ROOT` the second is `RELATIVE` to the current directory.

Comment: yeah but you can do ./src/dictionary.txt

Answer (score 0):

- Check character case is correct, the file has to be named "dictionary.txt" with correct cases
- Check where you placed the file in relative to where you run your java code. By default if you specify relative path such as "src/dictionary.txt", java will look it up from `System.getProperty("user.dir")`