# java writing file error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream

I have a question about writing csv file on the current project in eclipse

```
    public static void Write_Result(String Amount_Time_Dalta) throws IOException{

    File file;
    FileOutputStream fop = null;
    String content = "";
    String All_Result[] =  Amount_Time_Dalta.split("-");
    String path ="/Users/Myname/Documents/workspace/ProjectHelper/"+All_Result[1] + ".csv";
    System.out.println(path);
    content = All_Result[3]+ "," + All_Result[5] + "\n";
    System.out.println(content);
    file = new File(path);
    fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
    file.getParentFile();

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }


    byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

    fop.write(contentInBytes);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();
}
```

and I am getting error which is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:215)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
at FileDistributor.Write_Result(FileDistributor.java:59)
at FileDistributor.main(FileDistributor.java:29)
```

I used

```
String path ="/Users/Myname/Documents/workspace/ProjectHelper/";
```

path to read a files. I was working fine.
However, when I am using same path to write result to file ( can be exist or not. I create or overwrite a file.) it returns Invalid file path.... I am not really sure why..

updated

> just found interesting thing. when i just use File newTextFile = new File("1000".csv); then it is working. however, when i replace to File newTextFile = new File(filename +".csv"); it doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891510/java-io-filenotfoundexception-error-is-occuring

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a valid path from which a File object can be created:

```
/Users/Myname/Documents/workspace/ProjectHelper/
```

But if you look at it a second time, you'll see that it refers to a directory, not a writable file. What's your file name?

What does your `System.out.println` say is the value of `All_Result[1]`?

Sample Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] array = {"1000.csv", "800.csv", "700.csv"};
        File file;
        FileOutputStream fop;

        // Uncomment these two lines

        //String path = "c:\\" + array[0];
        //file = new File(path);

        // And comment these next two lines, and the code still works

        String path = "c:\\";
        file = new File (path + array[0]);

        // Sanity check

        System.out.println(path);

        try
        {
            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException opening output stream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("IOException opening creating new file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to get this code to break, instead of passing `array[0]` as a file name, just pass in an empty string `""` and you can reproduce your error.

Comment: MarsAtomic // it is string type array. It will be a name of file. it will be like 1000.csv file

Comment: Sure, but I'm not asking "what should the file name be?" I'm asking you what the file name actually is. When you append All_Result[1] to the path, you might think you're getting "path/1000.csv" but you're actually getting "path/" because All_Result[1] is empty. You even have a System.out.println to double check that, so what is the actual output there?

Comment: it will be 1000.csv ....800.csv. I just found interesting thing. when i just use  File newTextFile = new File("1000".csv); then it is working. however, when i replace to  File newTextFile = new File(filename +".csv");  it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, I'm not asking what the file name WILL be. I'm asking what it IS when you run your System.out.println. Just run the code and tell me what the System.out.println literally says. Copy and paste the output, full stop.

Comment: Sorry, misread something in your code. Set a breakpoint in your debugger right after you finish building your path variable, complete with the original path and the filename with extension. Then look at the value of path at that point and tell me exactly what it says. I'm almost certain it does NOT say what you think it should say.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem and was looking for answer. I tried using string.trim() and put it into the outputstream and it worked. I am guessing there are some trailing characters or bits surrounding the file path